# recovering chrome tab identity

Tags: tabs, google-chrome-extension

I would like to compute the identity of tabs in the chrome browser in a way that survives a browser restart. I am trying to implement the solution proposed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005258/persistent-unique-id-for-chrome-tabs-that-lasts-between-browser-sessions).

In my bg.htmtl, I wrote the following event handler:

```
chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(
    function(win) {
        console.log("window.onCreated", win);
        for(tab in win.tabs) {
            console.log("window.created.tab", tab);
        }
    });
```

I then create a new window by pressing `ctl-n` with the focus on Chrome, but I don't get the event to fire. I then create a second tab via `ctrl-t` and the event still doesn't fire. I then close the window, create a new window again, and then reload the previously closed ' 2 tabs' item in the recently-closed list. The event then fires. Unforunately, it is missing the tabs property, which is described as optional in the [documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#type-Window). I have "tabs" permission specified in my manifest.

What should I try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it very strange that your `onCreated` listener isn't being triggered on Ctrl-N. I just tested this and it worked fine for me. Are you absolutely sure you are looking in the right console?

Once you've got the `windowId`, you can retrieve the tabs using `chrome.windows.get` with the `populate` field set in the `getInfo` argument.

Comment: It's being triggered, but the tabs property is undefined.

Comment: Sure, so then call `chrome.windows.get` as I describe in my answer, using the `windowId` passed to your listener.