# Event when session restored after browser restart?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Is there a way detect when browser (re)started and session restored?

I've tried

```
chrome.sessions.onChanged.addListener((...args) =>
{
  console.log("chrome.sessions.onChanged fired", args);
});
```

but nothing logged.

*I'm trying store some data for each tab and since tab.id and tab.windowId [changes each time browser (re)started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005258/persistent-unique-id-for-chrome-tabs-that-lasts-between-browser-sessions?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C86.5515), I need to get notified when session is restored on startup, so I could update tabs database with new data.*

Comment: There's no such event. The closest one is chrome.runtime.onStartup. You'll have to find a different way to identify tabs e.g. a combination of url, title, index properties.

Comment: @wOxxOm I'm using tab's persistent properties to generate tab UUID, then from all tabs UUID in each window I generate window UUID. This seems to work reliably when session automatically restored on startup, however when browser starts with message "closed unexpectedly" (after crash with restore button), this method doesn't work, because service worker already launched and it triggers tabs.onCreated event for each restored tab...

Comment: Then add a check for this case. You won't be able to detect it reliably of course, so you can show a button in your popup to undo the assumption.